# Detach worktree based on working directory in git

Tags: git

I have a project that takes a few minutes to compile. Usually I do:

`$ git worktree add --detach ../my-project-build HEAD`

and then I have another terminal window at `my-project-build` to compile. When I'm done I delete the directory.

How can I create a worktree from my working directory (including uncommitted changes and untracked files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.  The `git worktree add` command uses `git checkout` to populate the new work-tree, and `git checkout` can only read commits.<sup>1</sup>

What you can do instead is make an archive (`tar` or `rar` or whatever) of your current work-tree—presumably excluding the `.git` directory or file—and extract that archive elsewhere, perhaps even atop an added work-tree (detached if you like).  As long as your archiver preserves timestamps as well as files, you will get just what you want.  There are several archive-ish tools that just copy from one tree to another, such as rsync.

---

<sup>1</sup>In a technical sense, it *could* read specific `git add`-ed files via your index, but in practice that's too hard, and it doesn't cover untracked files at all.